# localhost:8080から/Mainに移動したときにエラーが出る

Tags: java, tomcat

現在ホストがlocalhostでの`localhost:8080`をtomcatで構築しました。
そして、/Main(`localhost:8080/Main`)にアクセスしたときに、JSPで現在時刻を表示させるようなプログラムを作ろうとしています。しかし、実際にMainにアクセスしたときに、次のような「HTTP Status 404 – Not Found」という画面が出てきてしまいます。

以下のようなコードをVisual Studio Codeに打ち込み、実行しましたが、`The file Main.java is not executable, please select other files.`と出てきました。

**打ち込んだコード：**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Date;
import java.servlet.http.*;

@WebServlet("/Main")
public class Main extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doGet (HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponce res) throws IOException {
        Date d = new Date();
        PrintWriter w = res.getWriter();
        res.setContentType("text/html");
        w.write("<html><body>");
        w.write("Today is " + d.toString());
        w.write("</body></html>");

    }
}
```

**実際に出てきた画像:[image]**

Comment: Tomcat 上で実行するためには `war` という形式で作成したコード群をパッケージ化する必要があります。 例えば [こちらのサイト](https://www.zunouissiki.com/java-with-vcsode-with-tomcat-maven/) に手順が説明されていますので、この説明に沿って進めてみてください。その上で分からない点があれば質問文に追記してください。(現在質問として記載されている部分以外に問題点がありますが、現状それを推測できる情報がありません。)